# while retrieving data i would like to add 2 more coloumns..is it possible?

Tags: sql-server-2008

while retrieving data with Sp here using result of 1st case and 2nd case  i would like to add 2 more columns for that...is it possible???

```
alter proc spAccumlated1   @InstOrYear nvarchar(10)=null, @CentreCode  nvarchar(10)=null

as
begin
SELECT a.StudentCode,c.FullName,a.CentreCode,a.InstOrYear,d.BranchName,b.TotalPayment,a.BalanceAmt,

CASE 
         WHEN (b.TotalPayment > a.BalanceAmt) THEN (b.TotalPayment - a.BalanceAmt) 
         WHEN (b.TotalPayment = a.BalanceAmt) then '0'
         else '0'

END as ClosingAdv,
CASE 
         WHEN (a.BalanceAmt > b.TotalPayment) THEN (a.BalanceAmt - b.TotalPayment)
         WHEN (b.TotalPayment = a.BalanceAmt) then '0'
         else '0'
END as ClosingDebt

from StudentFees a
left  join PDF_Students c on c.Code = a.StudentCode 
left join CollectionPaymentDetails b on b.StudentCode = a.StudentCode
left join PDF_Branch d on d.code = a.CentreCode 
left join CollectionPayment e on e.CentreCode = b.CentreCode where a.InstOrYear=@InstOrYear and a.CentreCode=@CentreCode  --and a.instoryear=@SQL  --and @onemonth=@month 
END
```

Comment: What is result of this SP and what you expect (what columns)?

Comment: studentcode|fullname|CentreCode|InstorYear|Branchname|totalpayment|BalanceAmt|ClosingAdv|ClosingDebt|   result will be retrieving all columns data and and calculating ClosingAdv and ClosingDebt but i want to insert 2 columns openAdv,OpenDebt by using values of ClosingAdv and ClosingDebt ....

Comment: And `OpenAdv` using `ClosingAdv` returns what result ?

Comment: ClosingAdv returns sum of TotalPayment and balanceAmt.this value should come in next month record of OpenAdv if Totalpayment+ BalanceAmt is +ve or if negative ClosingDebt value will cum in OpenDebt sir

Comment: I don't understand, Can you post example in question with sample data?